# Evaluating this contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I am trying to show that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(0,3)}\frac{e^{(zk)}}{z^2+1}\mathrm dz = \sin k$$ for all $k \in \mathbb{C}$. And $\gamma(z_0,R)$ is the circular contour $z_0+Re^{it}$, where $0\le t\le 2\pi.$
I know I need to use contour integration, but I cant seem to solve this problem.

Do I possibly have to use $z=e^{it}$ and $\sin t=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\frac{1}{z})?$ Its just a thought, I most probably might be wrong on this..

Answer (score 6):

Easier way to go would be to write $\frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{{z^2} + 1}} = \frac{1}
{{2i}}\left( {\frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{z - i}} - \frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{z + i}}} \right)$ and then noticing that both singularities are located inside of your  contour of integration and that it is positively oriented. By applying residue theorem, you get $\frac{1}
{{2\pi i}}\int_{\gamma \left( {0,3} \right)} {\frac{{{e^{zk}}}}
{{{z^2} + 1}}dz}  = \frac{{{e^{ik}} - {e^{ - ik}}}}
{{2i}} = \frac{{\cos k + i\sin x - \cos \left( { - k} \right) - i\sin \left( { - k} \right)}}
{{2i}} = \sin k$

Comment: Thanks, shall work on it, I am not so confident with the residue theorem so I'll work on this!